# Need Help on Adaptive Streaming with JWPlayer

Tags: api, video-streaming, jwplayer

I'm currently exploring some features in JWPlayer that can help me achieve my aim that is video quality auto adjustment based on bandwith, usually called adaptive streaming. I have seen JWPlayer Javascript API from official JWPlayer website feature that I think can provide this to me. It is getQualityLevels(), but there is no documentation there, so I cannot start doing what I want.

Meanwhile I read from JWPlayer website in Streaming section, that I can use dynamic RTMP to get adaptive streaming. But it needs RTMP server and I think RTMP has lots of feature that I won't need because I just need adaptive streaming.

My question is
Is there any sample code that you can provide me to help me get adaptive streaming ?
Like how to get several video quality (SD,HD or 720px,1080px) from original video that I upload so that user can automatically select several video based on their bandwith ?

Please help me on this thing
Any answers is really appreciated,

Regards,
William

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of this API call in action - http://bit.ly/1ix120K

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ethan. But I think I still don't really get what I want. From the code in view source from link that you give to me, I can see that it define source video file for each of quality pixel available either in 480px or 720px. But what I want is JWPlayer automatically give video quality based on bandwidth in user that play the video besides specifically define each source video file of each quality. I want JWPlayer to automatically split my video into several video either in 360px, or 720px based on customer bandwidth. Does it can happen to be done using JWPlayer ?

Comment: This can be done, but only with HLS or RTMP streams, not progressive download.